# ms access 2016 how to divide column a into 10 columns using values from another column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

what I have is 3 fields 
movieid is autonumber 
pix is text 
columnid is numbered 1 to 10 recurring 
only used 3 in demo to save space and ordered on ColumnId

```
------------------------------------------------------
movieid       pix                           columnid
1             c:\photos\fred.jpg               1
2             c:\photos\jack.jpg               2
3             c:\photos\john.jpg               3
4             c:\photos\joan.jpg               1
5             c:\photos\jill.jpg               2 
6             c:\photos\derf.jpg               3
7             c:\photos\arab.jpg               1
8             c:\photos\fre.jpg                2 
9             c:\photos\fras.jpg               3
10            c:\photos\red.jpg                1 
11            c:\photos\ed.jpg                 2   
------------------------------------------------------
```

-what output i need is

```
------------------------------------------------------
column1           columnid    column2      columnid     column3  columnid
c:\photos\fred.jpg    1  c:\photos\jack.jpg   2   c:\photos\john.jpg    3
c:\photos\joan.jpg    1  c:\photos\jill.jpg   2   c:\photos\derf.jpg    3
c:\photos\arab.jpg    1  c:\photos\fre.jpg    2   c:\photos\fras.jpg    3
c:\photos\red.jpg     1  c:\photos\ed.jpg     2   etc
------------------------------------------------------
```

-hope this makes sense spent days trying to work it out with queries

Comment: This might require report with 10 subreports. I wanted to suggest a multi-column report with forced column break when the columnid changes but can't figure out how to do that in Access report. I have vague recollection of attempting that a long time ago and giving up in favor of the multiple subreports. I have used report with listboxes when I could be sure the amount of data would not extend beyond 1 page. Stretch listboxes to full length of page.

Comment: I tried using 10 querys each worked fine but when i went to combine them the 2nd column was the same record repeated over and over. Append query worked but column 2 started where column 1 finished and couldnt work out how to move it to the top of each column

Comment: Well, I already knew joining 10 queries for this data was not practical so did not even suggest. I did suggest a report with 10 subreports or 10 listboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, think I got something.

Query1:

```
SELECT movieid, columnid, pix, 
DCount("*","TableName","columnid=" & [ColumnID] & " AND movieid<" & [movieid])+1 AS SeqID
FROM TableName
ORDER BY movieid;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.pix) AS FirstOfpix
SELECT Query1.SeqID
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.SeqID
PIVOT Query1.columnid;
```

Been using that DCount() calc in a lot of answers past couple weeks. Shouldn't have taken me so long to think of for this question.

Comment: Thanks a million mate been buggin me for days works  a treat been learning SQL ,VBA,C++ online but its slow goin and im kinda old lol but I do love this stuff Its Challenging.